# How to burp my 2 months old newborn baby just after vaccination?

Tags: newborn, health, pain, immunizations

Tomorrow is the day my baby gets the 2 months vaccines. I know it's going to be a busy day for us as parents. I'm worried about how to burp my baby and not hurt him, because it can bring back the vaccination pain in case we accidentally touch his small injuries.

Answer (score 9):

If you touch it and it hurts, you'll know. While it is not nice to see your baby hurt, you will not irreparably damage your child if you happen to touch a sore spot. They're probably going to bump into it several times themselves.

The pain from trapped gas by avoiding burping might be worse, if your baby has a sensitive gut. Our baby is prone to painful gas and I did not see him suffer from his vaccinations to the same degree.

Our baby was injected in the top front of his thighs, which is not where you generally hold a baby anyway. We only touched it once during a bath and he cried for less than 5 seconds.

It's good to take care of your little one, but they're not *that* fragile. You'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Same as normal, they’re not going to be injecting him on his back.